# How to Change Heroku-Postgresql DB password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Simple question but my googling has completely failed me.

How do you change the password for the postgres database for a Heroku Rails application?

Comment: Why do you want to change the password? Heroku uses its own generated user and password for its databases.  You can tell it to use a different database by setting the DATABASE_URL environment variable, but I don't think you can change their user:pass combination.  Check the [Heroku database docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database).

Comment: E.g. if your db/pass was leaked or accidentally pushed to a public source control repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This used to not be possible, but now with the new Heroku Postgres plans you can now 'rotate' your database credentials.

You can do this via `heroku pg:credentials HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL --reset` where the HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL is the correct name based on your `heroku config` output.

On old plans, where this may be unsupported, you may be able to get heroku support to do it if you logged a ticket although they'll probably want a valid reason.

Comment: This is no longer the best answer. `pg:credentials:rotate` is correct as per [this support page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials)

Answer (score 12):

`heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset` ought to do it

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: It doesn't even prompt me to set a new password. What did it do? is it empty?

Answer (score 5):

`pg:credentials --reset` is deprecated. Please use `pg:credentials:rotate` instead

```
heroku pg:credentials:rotate DATABASE -a sushi
```

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials